# Select only specific ID or Users in Manager and managers2

Tags: php, sql

Hi I am currently working on my php project.

which is I need to get the specific users/Managers approval only.

This is my code from my project, but the problem is all user can see the User's of my php.

```
$managers=$conn->query("SELECT * from `users` where type = 3");

$managers2=$conn->query("SELECT * from `users` where type = 3");
```

`type = '3'` this is the User and also there is an Manager that using my php.

`type = '1'` is my admin and `type = '2'` is the staff.

is there any option to choose only the specific user by choosing the table of "id"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lehgB.png)

Comment: How about `SELECT * from users where id = 1`? I don't know though, the way you wrote the question is very unclear and the data sample is limited. See [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: Sorry about the unclear question, 

my question if it is possible to select only the specific user from my database .. 

Type = 1 is the admin
type = 2 is the staff
type = 3 is the user/appover 

but in my case i use this 
$managers=$conn->query("SELECT * from users where type = 3");
which is type = 3 users/managers >>
I have specific Managers only that who can see the service? is that possible i will choose ID only not the type that I created in every user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear but i understand a little bit you can put a AND condition to your WHERE statement like this `Where id = 1 AND type = 1`.

If your talking about access of the page you can do a IF Else Statement and Throw them to different URL like `if(type == 1){header('Location: admin.php')}`

Comment: Oh thank you! I have a bad english and bad explanation! hahaha I will try this AND condition, I think this is the answer of my question.

Thank you !